# how to add skin to a video element in html5

Tags: html, video

I am creating a retro style website. In which I want to add a video element. I want the video element to be surrounded with a retro style tv image. Do you know how to embed the video element inside the tv image?

Comment: Could you post some example code? Do you need the video to be above the image or under the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to create a Div and set the background image to be your retro TV.

The add another div inside this for you HTML5 video view.

Adjust the size of you video view div so that it fills the 'screen' part of your background TV picture.

You could even get very fancy and have hovers over certain areas of the background image correspond to the video controls...